# Бесплатные альтернативы JSdelivr

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, github, cdn

Есть ли бесплатные альтернативы JSdelivr для хранения личного JavaScript кода в облаке так, чтобы потом можно было подключить его в свой проект через тег `<script src="cdn.com/myjs.js">`?

JSdelivr хороший проект но мне не нравится что код который через него можно сохранить не обновляется автоматически. Т.е. нужно создавать новую версию кода или новую ветку  в GitHub и снова генерировать ссылку подключения через JSdelivr.

Есть ли альтернативы?